# loop doesn't work inside `onreadystatechange`

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, getelementsbytagname, onreadystatechange

here is my code:

```
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {

              if (this.readyState == 4)

                  if( this.status == 200) {
                  response = xmlhttp.responseXML;
                  var channel = response.documentElement;
                  var title = channel.getElementsByTagName("title")[0].firstChild.nodeValue;

                  var parent =  document.getElementById("journalTitle");
                  parent.innerHTML = title;

                  var articleList = document.getElementById("articleList");

                  item = channel.getElementsByTagName("item");
                  var list = new Array();
                  itemSize = (channel.getElementsByTagName("item").length);
                  var i =0;
                  do{

                      list[i] = item[i].getElementsByTagName("title")[0].firstChild.nodeValue;

                      item = document.createElement("div");
                      item.innerHTML = list[i];
                      articleList.appendChild(item);
                      i++;


                  }while(i=itemSize);

                }
```

the `size` variable is 22 and when I write `alert(item[5].getElementsByTagName("title")[0].firstChild.nodeValue);` it shows me the fifth element and so on, but inside the loop it just understand the first element of item for the rest it returns error :

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'getElementsByTagName' of undefined`

Comment: `while(i=itemSize)`???

Comment: what should I write instead?

Comment: I used for and it didn't work, so I changed `for` to `while`. the problem must be sth else :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my problem so ridiculous. although the while was incorrect, the for didn't work neither. the problem was that I have used different variables with the same name `item` . the problem was solved when I changed the code like so:

```
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {

          if (this.readyState == 4)

              if( this.status == 200) {
              response = xmlhttp.responseXML;
              var channel = response.documentElement;
              var title = channel.getElementsByTagName("title")[0].firstChild.nodeValue;

              var parent =  document.getElementById("journalTitle");
              parent.innerHTML = title;

              var articleList = document.getElementById("articleList");

              item = channel.getElementsByTagName("item");
              var list = new Array();
              itemSize = (channel.getElementsByTagName("item").length);

              for (i = 0;i<itemSize;i++){

                  list[i] = item[i].getElementsByTagName("title")[0].firstChild.nodeValue;

                  itemD = document.createElement("div");
                  itemD.innerHTML = list[i];
                  articleList.appendChild(itemD);


              }

            } 
 }
```

Comment: To be exact, I've mentioned variables with a same name in my answer, which has been posted two days ago...

Answer (score 1):

Your condition in the `while` loop is not comparing anything. It's a definition, setting the value of `i` to `itemSize` (which is 22 according to OP). If this wouldn't cause an error later in the script, you'd have an infinite loop, since `22` is evaluated to `true` in the condition of `while`.

The body of the `do...while` loop is always executed at least once. On the first round, `i` is `0`, and you get the expected results. However, when the second round begins, `i` equals to `22`, since it has got a new value in the `while(i=itemSize)`.

`getElementsByTagName()` returns an array-like object, which has zero-based indexing, i.e. the largest index in the `item` is `21`. On the second round of the loop you're trying to use `getElementsByTagName` method of `undefined` (`item[22].getElementsByTagName(...)...`, this causes the error message.

There's also a naming collision in the loop (the original `item` list is replaced with a DOM element), though this might be just a typo in the post. However, if the variable will be renamed, the indexing issue would remain.

I'd suggest you to use a `for` loop instead of `do...while`, just in case, there wouldn't be any items in `item`:

```
for (i = 0; i < itemSize; i++) {
    list[i] = item[i].getElementsByTagName("title")[0].firstChild.nodeValue;
    itemEl = document.createElement("div"); // renamed the variable
    itemEl.innerHTML = list[i];
    articleList.appendChild(itemEl);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {

              if (this.readyState == 4)

                  if( this.status == 200) {
                  response = xmlhttp.responseXML;
                  var channel = response.documentElement;
                  var title = channel.getElementsByTagName("title")[0].firstChild.nodeValue;

                  var parent =  document.getElementById("journalTitle");
                  parent.innerHTML = title;

                  var articleList = document.getElementById("articleList");

                  item = channel.getElementsByTagName("item");
                  var list = new Array();
                  itemSize = (channel.getElementsByTagName("item").length);
                  var i =0;
                  do{

                      list[i] = item[i].getElementsByTagName("title")[0].firstChild.nodeValue;

                      item = document.createElement("div");
                      item.innerHTML = list[i];
                      articleList.appendChild(item);
                      i++;


                  }while(i=itemSize);

                } 
} /*<---missing bracket here*/
```